# Refactor recursive string search to bisection search, hits max recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion

I have a very simple function which correctly searches if a character is in an alphabetical ordered string:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return False
    if char == aStr[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return isIn(char, aStr[1:])
```

Now I have tried to make it into a bisection search:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    hi = len(aStr) - 1
    lo = 0
    mid = abs(hi+lo)/2
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return False
    if char == aStr[mid]:
        return True
    if char < aStr[mid]:
        return  isIn(char, aStr[:mid])
    elif char > aStr[mid]:
        return  isIn(char, aStr[mid:])
```

It always exceeds the max recursion depth, even if `aStr` is just a few characters.  I don't understand why it doesn't terminate.  If my input `aStr` is `len` 4, it should search a mid value of 4+0/2 = 2, next time around 2+0/2 = 1, next time 1+0/2 = 0, next time `len` should = 0 and the recursion should terminate.

I've tried some strategically placed `print`s around, but can't figure it out.

This is homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issues here are that the pythonic behavior of numbers means that without any further indication of typing desired, `1/2 == 0`, and that string slicing doesn't work like you're assuming.

Each time you have `len(aStr) == 2`, `mid = 0`, and `a_string[0:] == a_string`, meaning you're never paring down your string for the next recursion. You need to consider how to handle the base case of `len(aStr) == 2`, since it occurs here, or how to prevent you from passing down the same string over and over.

(hint: consider that `a_string[index:]` is *inclusive* of the character at `index` -- but you've already ruled out `a_string[index]` as being a potential match...)

Answer (score 2):

If `len(aStr)==1` or `len(aStr)==2` and `char>aStr[0]`, then you'll have `mid=0` and this will recursively call `isIn(char,aStr[0:])` which is exactly the same as `isIn(char,aStr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll avoid spoiling too much. :)

The key of tackling recursion issues is making sure every possible input hits an escape clause - we want your functions to actually produce results.

The bisection will recurse every time splitting the string into halves - we we need to make sure our algorithm works properly handling strings of length zero and one.

You handled the zero-length strings nicely with the `if len(aStr) == 0`, so it must be something with one-character longs strings.

So, we're dealing with a string consisting of a single character.

What happens if the character is the one we're looking for? You're dealt with it promptly with your  `if char == aStr[mid]:`.

But **what happens if it isn't?** The string is one character long, so we can answer it without going deeper into recursion.

Do you see it now?